# Should I use "who" or "that" when referring to an organisation?

Tags: word-choice

I generally use the rule of thumb of using *who* when referring to a person and *that* when referring to an object. Example:

*Jim is someone **who** makes me smile.

I was nearly knocked out by the ball **that** hit me.*

But what about when we're talking about an organisation?

*I am forever indebted to the charities **who** helped me.

I am forever indebted to the charities **that** helped me*.

The former seems somewhat warmer, if that makes sense, although the latter feels more correct. What should I use? And how about this:

*I'm really happy with the insurance company **who** helped me with my claim.

I can't stand them, they're the insurance company **that** ripped me off.*

To me the former evokes a team of helpful people while the latter evokes a cold heartless corporate entity. Is this just a matter of style and so should go with my instincts, or should I aim for what is 'correct?'

Comment: Question obviously different but reminds me of British/American divide on whether to refer to groups in the plural or singular.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I couldn't find an authoritative source, but I found several items that touched on the question. The basic differential is that "who" refers strictly to people, and "that" can refer only to anything else:

> She is the woman who raised me

not

> She is the woman that raised me

Conversely,

> There is the school that educated me

and not

> There is the school who educated me.

The conflict arises here because you're using these companies anthropomorphically - you're happy with them, you're indebted to them. In reality, you're happy with the people AT the companies / charities, not the companies / charities themselves.

So I would go with

> I am forever indebted to the charities
>   that helped me.

or

> I am forever indebted to the people
>   who helped me

Comment: I had the same problem. +1 for suggestion re-wording as a solution. In my case, I ended up going with `people who` rather than `an organisation who`. I think it reads better now.

Comment: You have hit the nail on the head. A company/charity is NOT the people WHO work for the organisation.

Answer (score 1):

As reported from the NOAD (*New Oxford American Dictionary*), *that* is used to replace *who*, *whom*, and *which*; it is also used to introduce a defining or restrictive clause, especially one essential to identification.

> The book that I've just written.

In the sentence *I'm really happy with the insurance company that helped me with my claim*, *helped me with my claim* identifies the company you are happy with; you are not happy with every companies.
The same is true for *I am forever indebted to the charities that helped me*.