# Who or what or which?

Tags: who, what

Is it

> Who are the main competitors?

or

> What are the main competitors?

The word `competitor' is referring to a firm / company here. If it were referring to a person, then I would say the first version is correct. However, in the current case I am doubting if the second option would be correct.

[Related question.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/138110/who-or-which-in-reference-to-companies)

Comment: Related: [Should I use 'who' or 'that' when referring to an organisation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12237/should-i-use-who-or-that-when-referring-to-an-organisation) (the charity who/that ...).

Comment: No reference (so not an answer), but I'd go with the first, at least outside the most formal of contexts.  We're treating organisations on the same terms as living entities (and in law, a company is considered a legal "person") so this seems reasonable.

Comment: I think I'd go with 'who' as being the most idiomatic here; the notional tie is that companies are made up of people. (Though I was never quite happy with 'The Ship who Sang', Anne McCaffrey.)

Comment: On whose side of the Atlantic are you?

Comment: @HotLicks It's a mistake to think that that matters here.